# Can a CNAME record not include www?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

My registrar tell me that I can't have a CNAME record that doesn't start with www. Is it true?

So I am using amazon ec2 with load balancing. the loadbalancer has a convoluted DNS name, and specifically tells you to use a CNAME to send requests to that DNS name, and not an A record.

> myloadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com (A Record)
>
> Note: Because the set of IP addresses associated with a LoadBalancer can change over time, you should never create an "A" record with any specific IP address. If you want to use a friendly DNS name for your load balancer instead of the name generated by the Elastic Load Balancing service, you should create a CNAME record for the LoadBalancer DNS name, or use Amazon Route 53 to create a hosted zone. For more information, see Using Domain Names With Elastic Load Balancing.

I purchased a domain. The registrar doesn't allow you to add records yourself, only by emailing them a request. So they set up a CNAME record

```
mydomain.org  SOA 111  whatever
www.mydomain.org    CNAME   3596    myloadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

when I asked them why it doesn't work with `www`, the registrar answered that there is a technical prohibition to make a CNAME record without `www`. Is it true, or are they incompetent/lying and I should switch registrars?

Comment: You phrase your question a bit awkwardly, the *"technical prohibition to make a CNAME record without www"*  applies the bare domain, i.e. `example.com` or `example.co.uk`  also called the apex. That's why I close your question as a duplicate. In addition to `www` any other valid hostname can be used as CNAME records i.e. `www2.example.com.` , `ftp.servers.example.com.` etc. can all be CNAME's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CNAME (Alias) record points to an A (Host) record. You can create multiple CNAME records and point them to an A record. The most common CNAME record used is the subdomains www, which is supported by every provider. You can also use Route53 to create A or CNAME. it supports 'www'.

Cheers!!

Tested Solution :

Update - To solve your problem you can use route 53 to create an A record for the ELB using root domain such as 'example.com' and CNAME as www.example.com.

Comment: a cname can point to another cname too. anyway, my problem is that cname records for root addresses are not allowed

Comment: In route 53 you can use Alias record for the root address (which is called Apex zone) check out here..          https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

Answer (score 4):

This is utter nonsense. A CNAME record can be as arbitrary as an A record.  This crap together with the fact they need emails to change records is a clear hint to run!

Edit: 
To avoid confusion: Having a CNAME point to the zone itself (like `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`, this is called the Apex) is not possible, but I thought you wanted to have something else then `www` as the name, e.g. `myserver.example.com`).

Comment: well, to try it out, I went to Amazon Route 53, and they also don't allow CNAME on apex zone (whatever that means)

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

A CNAME resource record cannot point at a zone, RFC1034: "If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot be different."  Therefore you can't have a CNAME and an SOA called mydomain.org, so they are partly correct.

However, www is not special, it's just a string and your registrar should allow you to specify what that string should be, such as myserver.mydomain.org.